# create loop through every cell in specific range of multiple google sheets and if condition true do the task

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to create loop through every cell in specific range of multiple google sheets and if the cell has no formula and the cell is not blank then Clear the Cell Value.

I have tried this but here I have to mentioned the every Range/Cell Address Manually and I have to run this in every sheet.

Script

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Reset sheet')
  .addItem('Reset Current Sheet', 'ResetCurrentSheet')
  .addToUi();
}
function ResetCurrentSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangesAddressesList = ['D6', 'D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'D11', 'D12', 'D13', 'D14', 'D15', 'D17', 'D19', 
  'D20', 'D21', 'D23', 'D25', 'D26', 'D27', 'D28', 'D29', 'D30', 'D31', 'D32', 'D33', 'D34', 'D35', 'D36',
  'D37', 'D38', 'D40', 'D41', 'D42', 'D43', 'D45', 'D46', 'D47', 'D48', 'D49', 'D50', 'D51', 'D52', 'D54', 
  'D55', 'D56', 'D57', 'D58', 'D59', 'D60', 'D61', 'D63', 'D64', 'D65', 'D67', 'D68', 'D69', 'D70', 'D71', 
  'D72', 'D73', 'D75', 'D76', 'D77', 'D78', 'D79', 'D80', 'D81', 'D82', 'D83', 'D84', 'D85', 'D86', 'D87', 
  'D88', 'D90', 'D91', 'D92', 'D93', 'D94', 'D95', 'D96', 'D97', 'D98', 'D99', 'D100', 'D101', 'D102', 'D103',
  'D104', 'D105', 'D106', 'D108', 'D109', 'D110', 'D111', 'D112', 'D114', 'D115', 'D116', 'D117', 'D119', 'D120', 
  'D121', 'D123', 'D124', 'D125', 'D126', 'D127', 'D129', 'D130', 'D131', 'D132', 'D133', 'D134', 'D135', 'D136',
  'D137', 'D139', 'D141', 'D143', 'D144', 'D146', 'D148', 'D149', 'D150', 'D151', 'D152', 'D153', 'D155', 'D157', 
  'D158', 'D160', 'D161', 'D162', 'D163', 'D164', 'D165', 'D166', 'D167', 'D168', 'D170', 'D171', 'D173', 'D174', 
  'D175', 'D176', 'D177', 'D178', 'D180', 'D182', 'D183', 'D184', 'D185', 'D186', 'D187', 'D188', 'D189', 'D190',
  'D191', 'D192', 'D193', 'D194', 'D195', 'D196', 'D197', 'D198', 'D199', 'D200', 'D201', 'D202', 'D203', 'D204', 
  'D206', 'D208', 'D210', 'D212', 'D214', 'D216', 'D217', 'D219',];
  resetByRangesList_(sheet, rangesAddressesList);
}
function resetByRangesList_(sheet, rangesAddressesList){
  sheet.getRangeList(rangesAddressesList).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: This isn't a code conversion service. What do you have so far in Google Apps Script?

Comment: Hi Ross I have added my code please check if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES5:

```
function resetAllSheets() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shnA=['Sheet236','Sheet237','Sheet238'];//Put your own sheet names in here
  var s="D6,D8,D9,D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15,D17,D19,D20,D21,D23,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31,D32,D33,D34,D35,D36,D37,D38,D40,D41,D42,D43,D45,D46,D47,D48,D49,D50,D51,D52,D54,D55,D56,D57,D58,D59,D60,D61,D63,D64,D65,D67,D68,D69,D70,D71,D72,D73,D75,D76,D77,D78,D79,D80,D81,D82,D83,D84,D85,D86,D87,D88,D90,D91,D92,D93,D94,D95,D96,D97,D98,D99,D100,D101,D102,D103,D104,D105,D106,D108,D109,D110,D111,D112,D114,D115,D116,D117,D119,D120,D121,D123,D124,D125,D126,D127,D129,D130,D131,D132,D133,D134,D135,D136,D137,D139,D141,D143,D144,D146,D148,D149,D150,D151,D152,D153,D155,D157,D158,D160,D161,D162,D163,D164,D165,D166,D167,D168,D170,D171,D173,D174,D175,D176,D177,D178,D180,D182,D183,D184,D185,D186,D187,D188,D189,D190,D191,D192,D193,D194,D195,D196,D197,D198,D199,D200,D201,D202,D203,D204,D206,D208,D210,D212,D214,D216,D217,D219";
  var rgA=s.split(',');
  var rowA=rgA.map(function(e){return parseInt(e.slice(1));});
  for(var i=0;i<shnA.length;i++) {
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(shnA[i]);
    var rg=sh.getRange(rgA[0] + ':' + rgA[rgA.length-1]);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var fA=rg.getFormulas();
    var sr=rowA[0];
    for(var j=0;j<vA.length;j++) {
      var n=Number(j+sr);
      var idx=rowA.indexOf(n);
      if(idx!=-1 && !fA[j][0]){
        vA[j][0]='';
      }else if(idx!=-1 && fA[j][0]){
        vA[j][0]=fA[j][0];
      }
    }
    rg.setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thanks for the code. By the way when saving this code it showing some error at Line 4. SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: That should be better.  I left the anonymous function declaration out.

Answer (score 1):

[`get`Formulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getformulas) and [`set`Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setValues(Object)):

```
function resetAllSheets() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheets()
    .forEach(sheet => {
      const rg = sheet.getDataRange();
      rg.setValues(rg.getFormulas());
    });
}
```

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: Hi TheMaster Thanks for your code, it is working fine. But it deletes all heading and others cells also. I want it for a specific ranges 'D6:D217' and 'I6:Z217' and also want to exclude the Sheet Name: 'Master Sheet'.

Comment: @Amit Kindly read the documentation and try to achieve the new goal  yourself. If you're unable, ask a new question adding in your efforts so far.